# sorting row by logic conditions pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, row, conditional-statements

I am trying to sort rows within column sample.single by excluding ('./.'). The all data types are objects. I have attempted the options below. I suspect the special character is compromising the second attempt. Dataframe is comprised of 195 columns.

My gtdata columns:

Index(['sample.single', 'sample2.single', 'sample3.single'] dtype='object')

Please advise, thank you!

```
gtdata = gtdata[('sample.single')!= ('./.') ]
```

I receive a key error: KeyError: True

When I try:

```
gtdata = gtdata[gtdata.sample.single != ('./.') ]
```

I receive an attribute error:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'single'

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Type ('sample.single')!= ('./.') into the interpreter. It will return True. You should be able to work out why. This means that gtdata[('sample.single')!= ('./.') ] means you are trying to evaluate gtdata[True]. Presumably that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but assuming you have cells containing the "./." string which you want to filter out, the below is one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# generate some sample data
gtdata = pd.DataFrame({'sample.single': ['blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3./.'], 
                       'sample2.single': ['blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3'], 
                       'sample3.single': ['blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3']})

# filter out all cells in column sample.single containing ./.
gtdata = gtdata[~gtdata['sample.single'].str.contains("./.")]
```

When subsetting in Pandas you should be passing a boolean vector with the same dimension as the DataFrame.

The problem with your first approach was that `('sample.single')!=('./.')` evaluates into a single boolean value as opposed to a boolean vector. You're also comparing two strings, not any column in the DataFrame.

The problem with your second approach is that `gtdata.sample.single` doesn't make sense in pandas syntax. To get the `sample.single` column you have to refer to is as gtdata['sample.single']. If your column name did not contain a ".", you could use the shorthand that you were trying to use: e.g. `gtdata.sample_single`.

I recommend reviewing the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for subsetting Pandas DataFrames.

Comment: Thank you Ido! Just had to add a '\' to escape the special characters in your code but works!
    [gtdata = gtdata[~gtdata['sample.single'].str.contains('\./.')]]